# Postgres SQL regexp_replace replace all number

Tags: sql, postgresql, replace, regexp-replace

I need some help with the next. I have a field text in SQL, this record a list of times sepparates with '|'. For example

'14613|15474|3832|148|5236|5348|1055|524' Each value is a time in milliseconds. This field could any length, for example is perfect correct '3215|2654' or '4565' (only 1 value). I need get this field and replace all number with -1000 value.

So '14613|15474|3832|148|5236|5348|1055|524' will be '-1000|-1000|-1000|-1000|-1000|-1000|-1000|-1000'

Or '3215|2654' => '-1000|-1000' Or '4565' => '-1000'.

I try use regexp_replace(times_field,'[[:digit:]]','-1000','g') but it replace each digit, not the complete number, so in this example:

'3215|2654' than must be '-1000|-1000', i get:

'-1000-1000-1000-1000|-1000-1000-1000-1000', I try with other combinations and more options of regexp but i'm done.

Please need your help, thanks!!!.

Answer (score 2):

We can try using `REGEXP_REPLACE` here:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET times_field = REGEXP_REPLACE(times_field, '\y[0-9]+\y', '-1000', 'g');
```

If instead you *don't* really want to alter your data but rather just view your data this way, then use a select:

```
SELECT
    times_field,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(times_field, '\y[0-9]+\y', '-1000', 'g') AS times_field_replace
FROM yourTable;
```

Note that in either case we pass `g` as the fourtb parameter to `REGEXP_REPLACE` to do a global replacement of all pipe separated numbers.

Answer (score 1):

`[[:digit:]]` - matches a digit [0-9]

`+` Quantifier - matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible

your regexp must look like

`regexp_replace(times_field,'[[:digit:]]+','-1000','g')`

Comment: Thanks a lot!!. It works and was so simple, I really give you +1 votes, but i can't for my reputation.

"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." :(